# How to remove console.log from production?

Tags: laravel-mix

How can I remove all console.log from production. This code isn't working on **laravel-mix 4.x**:

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.options({
      uglify: {
        uglifyOptions: {
          warnings: false,
          comments: false,
          beautify: false,
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
          }
        }
      }
    });

    mix.version();
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `laravel-mix` 4.x they replaced `uglify` with `terser` ([Changelog](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/releases/tag/v4.0.0)). You have to change your **webpack.mix.js**:

```
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.options({
        terser: {
            terserOptions: {
                compress: {
                   drop_console: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mix.version();
}
```

Comment: **Bug:** All `terserOptions` get ignored for development builds (at least in Laravel-mix 5.0.9) - above's `if (mix.inProduction())` check is useless if said is intended (and not a bug).

Comment: Thanks, it's works ("laravel-mix": "^6.0.49"). Note that `mix.version()` is part of code from original question and can be removed if not needed.