# Laravel mix, webpack, terser - strip console log in production bundle

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, terser

I'm trying to strip console log and console debugs from the production build of my laravel + react app. I found many different solutions but none seemed suitable for my environment.

I'm still trying to understand the whole mix / webpack / terser pipeline.

what am I missing ?

*webpack.mix.js*

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').version()
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').version()
  .copy('resources/assets/img', 'public/assets/img').version()
  .copy('resources/assets/font', 'public/assets/fonts').version()
  .copy('resources/assets/logos', 'public/assets/logos').version()
  .copy('storage/app/public', 'public/storage').version();

mix.webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
    modules: [
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },
  // anything below this point is attempts that did not work.
  stats: "errors-only",
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: true,
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            drop_debugger: true
          },
          output: { comments: false, beautify: false }
        },
      }),
    ],
  }
});

if (!mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.webpackConfig({ devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' });
}
```

*package.json*

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use terser ? I never heard of it until now. What disadvantage brings Webpack (Laravel Mix) that Terser aids ?

Comment: I'm not trying to use anything in particular, terser is just the default compressor module used by laravel mix. cf https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/options If you know of another method that works I'll take it

Comment: I have no idea how to use it, nor I would modify it, but reading the [source code](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix), I see in [`src/config.js`](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/9971ef3eb3dc64d8379715d71c72b481b7f5788b/src/config.js#L137-L154) that there is a default config (maybe you want to see what it is). So anything you want to add or modify, I think you should follow the URL on top of it being [this one](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#options) so you can know what to edit directly there as a `terser webpack's config`.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#remove-comments) will help you.

Comment: thank you for your pointers but I still cannot get it to work. I see that terser is running in my build terminal but the logs are still presents in the final app. I cleared my cache and re-install my node modules just to be sure but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mix.webpack` try this:

```js
mix.options({
  terser: {
    terserOptions: {
      mangle: true,
      compress: {
        drop_console: true,
        drop_debugger: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        beautify: false
      }
    },
  },
});
```

You have to use `mix.options` to *set mix config* that is available in the [`config.js`](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/9971ef3eb3dc64d8379715d71c72b481b7f5788b/src/config.js#L137-L154).

---

This is just another SO post I found just now: [How to remove console.log from production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54257331/how-to-remove-console-log-from-production)

Comment: thanks again but it is still not working on my side. I must be doing something wrong somewhere else. To test it I've put your code chunk just after the mix import and I use `npm run watch` to launch my app. Is there any more information I could give you to help me get to the bottom of this ?

Comment: Oh, I don't think so. If that is not working, I have no idea then as I do not know nearly anything about it and it is pretty hard to debug JS.

Answer (score 0):

You probably check your build file's extension!
I'm not using laravel but struggling with this with my react project and solved it by adding test regex property for .js ([default is .mjs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/))

```js
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i, // you should add this property
        terserOptions: {
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            drop_debugger: true,
            pure_funcs: ['console.log', 'console.info'], // Delete console
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
```